# md5 doesnt work with certain characters

Tags: php, authentication, web, md5, change-password

I have set up a login/registration script for my website and i'm using md5 to encrypt my passwords, ive just set up a change password section however ive noticed that i can only change my passwords when they contain alphanumerics. For example if my old password were stack123 and i changed it to overflow123 it would work perfectly. But if i change it from stack 123 to stack! It would not and im guessing this is because of the exclamation mark in this case. Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: Noone can help you if you do not show your code.

Comment: MD5 is not secure.  Security is **hard**; do not reinvent the wheel.  You must use an existing, proven, authentication system.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation SLaks?

Comment: So what do you get if you do `md5('stack!')`? Does it throw an error? `md5` certainly doesn't.... it's more likely that you have some code elsewhere in your script that restricts password fields to alphanumerics only (which is incredibly bad practise)

Comment: Baker you're right my password field was only restricted to alphanumerics but from the comments and answers i recieved im going to use an existing authen system, nonetheless thanks for that, helped made things clear.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Do not use MD5. You should rather use [hash_hmac()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) or even better the new [PHP Hashing API](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) (if you have at least PHP 5.5). In order to make the password more secure, use a random generated, for every user a different salt (it's just a string full of random characters) and save it with the password in the database.

This is a function to generate a random string ($length determines the length of the returned string):

```
function generate($length) {
    $dummy = array_merge(range('0', '9'), range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'));
    shuffle($dummy);
    return substr(implode('', $dummy), 0, $length);
}
```

This is a code snippet for the PHP Hashing API:

```
function my_password_hash($salt, $password) {
    $phpapi_options = array("algo" => PASSWORD_BCRYPT, "salt" => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM), "cost" => 11);
    return password_hash(sha1($salt.$password), $phpapi_options['algo'], $phpapi_options);
}

function my_password_verify($salt, $password, $hash) {
    return password_verify(sha1($salt.$password), $hash);
}
```

my_password_hash() generates the hash for the given salt and password. my_password_verify() verifies the given password (user input) and salt (from the db) with the hash you've stored in your database.

This is a code snippet with hash_hmac():

```
function my_password_hash($salt, $password) {
    $hash_key = ""; //define a 10 characters long random generated string here (it has to be always the same)
    if(empty($hash_key)) {
        die('You must enter a valid hash key.');
    }

    return hash_hmac("sha512", sha1($salt.$password), $hash_key);
}

function my_password_verify($salt, $password, $hash) {
    if($hash == my_password_hash($salt, $password)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps a bit, if not or you have any questions, just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the info but im not very familiar with hash and salts so I googled around and came acros with usercake. usercake.com/ would you recommend using this they use  as quoted "a salt along with an SHA1 hash to encrypt passwords. The salt is 25 characters in length. This can be increased to 32 characters. Locate the generateHash() function in models/funcs.php to modify this." Would you recommend this

Comment: Well sha1() is better than md5(), but it's only a matter of time until there are sha1 rainbow tables on the internet. Just google "md5 rainbow tables" to get some for MD5. You should rather use one of the functions I said above. The use of these above is practically the same like the use of sha1() with salt from usercake.

Comment: Why on earth are you abusing the password functions like that? There is no reason to generate your own salt, nor is there a reason you want to ever first `sha1` the string

Comment: Also you should rather use `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` as algo to make your code and hashing more future proof because it will automatically use newer / stronger algo's when they are implemented in the future.

Comment: @PeeHaa: You're right, the own salt and the sha1() of the string isn't needed with the PHP Hashing API. But that doesn't mean it's useless. It does make the hash stronger. And why on earth are you talking about abusing the password functions? Instead of speaking large words, present your own answer.

Comment: "It does make the hash stronger" How would that make the hash stronger? What do you think `sha1` does to your entropy?

Comment: What exactly is PASSWORD_DEFAULT?

Comment: @Mojo it always uses the strongest algorithm available in php.

Comment: How would I implement this for my current reg system

Comment: I've used PASSWORD_DEFAULT. Thanks for all info everybody